# Most efficient way to search multiple things at once with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I want to search all entries for "Sprite", "Pepsi", or "Coke" in the title/description and output the last 3 results.

```
------------------------------------------------
| ID | Title                 | Description     |
------------------------------------------------
| 1  | text text SPRITE text | text PEPSI xxx  |
| 2  | text text text text   | text text text  |
| 3  | text text SPRITE text | text COKE xxxx  |
| 4  | text text text text   | text text text  |
| 5  | text PEPSI text text  | text COKE xxxx  |
| 6  | text COKE text text   | text COKE xxxx  |
| 7  | text text text text   | text text text  |
| 8  | text text text text   | text text text  |
------------------------------------------------
```

**Is this the most efficient query to do this?**

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE title LIKE '%Sprite%' OR description LIKE '%Sprite%'
      OR title LIKE '%Pepsi%' OR description LIKE '%Pepsi%'
      OR title LIKE '%Coke%' OR description LIKE '%Coke%'
ORDER BY 'id' DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Or is there a way to do it with MATCH AGAINST? (I couldnt find a way)..

**Example output:**

```
------------------------------------------------
| 6  | text COKE text text   | text COKE xxxx  |
| 5  | text PEPSI text text  | text COKE xxxx  |
| 3  | text text SPRITE text | text COKE xxxx  |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a fulltext search service. Sphinx, for example.

Comment: You should be able to do it with MATCH(title, description) AGAINST('sprite') etc. if you have a full-text index.

Comment: How do I MATCH AGAINST mutliple search terms at once?

Comment: OR operator is implied: `AGAINST('sprite pepsi coke' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` . Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE description regexp ('sprite|pepsi|coke')
ORDER BY 'id' DESC
```